# How can I get an XML attribute as below using file_get_contents or simplexml_load_file?

Tags: php, xml

How can I get the `firstname` of the XML below?

I am trying to use `file_get_contents` or `simplexml_load_file` and trying to echo the value like

```
$html->result[0]->contact;
```

without any luck. Can I have some help please?

[image]

Comment: Paste your xml __as text__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see full xml but I suppose it is:

```
$html->entities[0]->organization[0]->description;
$html->entities[0]->organization[0]->contacts[0]->contactPerson['firstName'];
```

Comment: OK, but how can I get the `firstName` that is in the `contactPerson`

Comment: With this logic, how can I get the organization id? I am trying with `$html->entities[0]->organization[0]->organization['id'];`

Comment: `$html->entities[0]->organization[0]['id']` or just `$html->entities[0]->organization['id']` if `organization` is single tag in file.